# Send post request from server to another by curl

Tags: php, curl, remote-server

I have 2 PHP files, each one in separated server.

For example:

1. mainServer/default/index.php
2. externalServer/request.php

**The first file code (index.php):**

```
echo $_POST['file_name'];
```

**The Second file code (request.php):**

```
$data = array(
    'file_name' => "file.zip",
    'file_size' => 5000
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mainServer/default/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What I want is send the `$data` array from `externalServer/request.php` to `mainServer/default/index.php`, but there is an error `Notice: Undefined index: file_name in default\index.php on line 13`.

How to get the `$data` array to for instance to print an item ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` outputs ?

Comment: @Akshay: The output: `array (size=0) empty`

Comment: Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in your code. Sending an associative array directly (what you did) is not a correct way. You need to send the array as a string.

**Example**

```
This->
$data = array(
    'file_name' => "file.zip",
    'file_size' => 5000
);
```

Should be This->

```
$data = "file_name=file.zip&file_zipe=500"
```

Now when you'd sent the data, you'd be able to fetch it via `$_POST`. You can let php do the `array to string conversion` using `http_build_query`.

```
$data = array(
        'file_name' => "file.zip",
        'file_size' => 5000
    );
$string = http_build_query($data);
//output = file_name=file.zip&file_size=5000
```

Read more about `http_build_query` [Here](http://php.net/http_build_query)